# Generating m numbers that equal 100 but difference between two numbers have to be greater than 4

Tags: javascript, oop, random, numbers

I'm trying to *generate numbers* that are equal 100(%) but all numbers have to be atleast 4 numbers from each other. So if I generate 4 numbers they have to be like this for example **[22,28,15,35]** and can't be like this **[22,28,20,30]** as difference between **28-30 and 22 - 20** is less than 4.

I was able to put together method for generating numbers that equal something which looks like this.

```
generate (max, many) {
    this.numbers_array = []
    this.normalized_numbers_array = []
    this.sum = 0 
    for (let i = 0; i < many; i++) {
      this.numbers_array.push(Math.random())
      this.sum += this.numbers_array[i]  
    }
    this.remaining = max
    for (let i = 0; i < this.numbers_array.length; i++) {
      this.outcome= (this.numbers_array[i] / this.sum) * max
      this.normalized_numbers_array[i] = Math.floor(this.outcome)
      this.remaining -= this.normalized_numbers_array[i]
      if (i + 1 == this.numbers_array.length) {
        while (this.remaining > 0) {
          this.normalized_numbers_array[i]++
          this.remaining--
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

And works fine. My next approach was trying to compare the normalized numbers with each other **through two for loops and if statements**. Then according to the differences between the numbers with each other I wanted **add 2% to one and substruct 2% from other** of the two numbers that are being compared. Then I put them in new array which I wanted to normalized again.

```
   for (let i = 0; i < this.normalized_numbers_array.length; i++) {

  for (let j = i + 1; j < this.normalized_numbers_array.length; j++) {

    if (Math.abs(this.normalized_numbers_array[i] - this.normalized_numbers_array[j]) < 5) {
        //do something
      if (this.normalized_numbers_array[i] > this.normalized_numbers_array[j]) {
        //do something
      } else if (this.normalized_numbers_array[i] <= this.normalized_numbers_array[j]) {
    //do something  
      }
    }
}
```

}

This approach is flawed, though. As by adding or substructing I can make new differences that are less than 4. For example **[35,18,26,21]->[35,16,26,23]**  Difference between 26 and 23 is 3 after the change.

My thought was to create another loop that would be going as long as there are differences. But I'm not sure that would work. So I was wondering whether there is better working solution for this problem- maybe being able to **generate those numbers with differences in size from the start** and not have to change them after.

Comment: is your interval from one to 100? [1, 100]?

Comment: No, it can be 0 as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Generate four uniform random numbers from the same range
- Scale them so they add up to 76 (100 - separators, see below); adjust randomly as needed to account for the remainder
- Insert separators: sort, then add 4 to the first, 8 to the second, 12 to the last one (and no adjustment to the zeroth).

Example

- Generate `[102, 387, 386, 284]`
- Scale: `[102, 387, 386, 284] * 76 / (102 + 387 + 386 + 284)` evaluates to `[6, 25, 25, 18]`
- Adjust: That's only 74, so randomly add `1` to two elements: `[6, 25, 26, 19]`
- Sort: `[6, 19, 25, 26]`
- Insert separators: `[6, 23, 33, 38]`

Adds up to 100, guaranteed to be at least 4 apart, [EDIT] very few loops (to ensure no division by zero), and with as little arbitrary disturbance of the distribution. For the curious, here's what it looks like:

```js
function f() {
  let q, s;
  while (!s) {
    q = Array.from({length: 4}, () => Math.random()); 
    s = q.reduce((a, e) => a + e);
  }
  q.forEach((e, i, q) => q[i] = (e * 76 / s)|0);
  s = q.reduce((a, e) => a + e);
  while (s < 76) {
    q[(Math.random() * 4)|0]++; s++;
  }
  q.sort((a, b) => a - b);
  q.forEach((e, i, q) => q[i] += i * 4);
  return q;
}


const N = 100000;
function draw() {
  const labels = ["#0", "#1", "#2", "#3", "Any"];
  const colours = ["red", "orange", "green", "blue", "black"];
  const data = Array.from({length:5}, (e, i) => ({
    label: labels[i],
    borderColor: colours[i],
    backgroundColor: i == 4 ? "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)" : "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
    pointRadius: 0,
    data: Array.from({length:100}, (e, i) => ({ x: i, y: 0 }))
  }));
  for (let s = 0; s < N; s++) {
    const q = f();
    q.forEach((e, i) => {
      data[i].data[e].y++;
      data[4].data[e].y++;
    });
  }

  const ctx = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('2d');
  const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        datasets: data
    },
    options: {
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      animation: false,
      legend: {
        position: 'right'
      },
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }],
        xAxes: [{
          type: 'linear',
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true,
            max: 100
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  });
};

draw();
document.querySelector('canvas').addEventListener('dblclick', draw);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas width="400" height="180"/>
```

Comment: 'and as uniformly random as possible' that is just not possible. Curious what distribution would be at the end.

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux: Yeah, I said that badly. I added the code and the distribution chart.

Comment: Cool. Could you run code from my answer using your visualisation? Just curious, how multinomial will behave (you could drop rejection, it is quite rare). Multinomial with probs [.1, .2, .3, .4] would be good comparison with yours

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux: Feel free to copy-paste it to your answer, and replace `function f` with your code.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<style>
.HideX{
 display:none;
};
</style>
<body>
<input type="text" id="QQ">
<input type="text" id="QQ2">
<script>
function isEmpty(map) {
   for(var key in map) {
     if (map.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        return false;
     }
   }
   return true;
}
function GetRandom(St,Range){
 return Math.floor((Math.random() * Range) + St);
}
function Pick4(){
 var BigPool={};
 var ResultX=[];
  //Generate [1,100]
 for(var i=1;i<=100;i++){
  BigPool[i.toString()]=i;
 }
 
 var Remain=100;
 var Last=100;
 for(var j=0;j<3;j++){
  if(isEmpty(BigPool)){//Althoght impossible but add this exception
   return Pick4();
  }
  var Pick=GetRandom(1,Remain);
  if(BigPool.hasOwnProperty(Pick.toString())){
   delete BigPool[Pick.toString()];//Remove Pick
   ResultX.push(Pick);
   Remain-=Pick;
   for(var i=Remain+1;i<=Last;i++){
    if(BigPool.hasOwnProperty(i.toString())){
     delete BigPool[i.toString()];//Remove above remain
    }
   }
      Last=Remain;
  }else{
   j--;
      continue;
  }
  for(var i=-3;i<=3;i++){//Remove [Pick-3,Pick+3]
   
   if(BigPool.hasOwnProperty((Pick+i).toString())){
    delete BigPool[(Pick+i).toString()];//Remove [Pick-3,Pick+3]
   }
   
  }
 }
 
 if(BigPool.hasOwnProperty(Remain.toString())){
  ResultX.push(Remain);
 }else{
  return Pick4();
 }
 
 
 
 
 return ResultX;
}
var G=Pick4();
document.getElementById("QQ").value = G;
document.getElementById("QQ2").value = G.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is simple answer

Comment: Maybe simple, but not correct as you are generating numbers that are not always atleast 4 numbers apart.

Answer (score 0):

A small brute force approach. After running, take a random result from the array.

```js
function get4() {

    function iter(temp, sum) {
        var i, s, t;

        for (i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
            s = sum + i;
            if (s > max) return;
            t = temp.concat(i);
            if (t.length === 4) {
                if (s === max) result.push(t.map((v, i) => v + 4 * i));
                continue;
            }
            iter(t, s);
        }
    }

    var result = [],
        max = 76;

    iter([], 0);
    return result;
}

var result = get4();

console.log(result.length);
console.log(result.map(a => a.join(' ')));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is stats driven approach to the problem, might be useful to look at the problem from different perspective. We will use [Multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution), which has natural property of sum being **always** equal to `n` (100 in your case). One could play with probabilities in such way, that difference between sampled numbers is very probable to be bigger than 4. Because mean values for multinomial are n`*`p<sub>i</sub>, we space probabilities far apart. After sampling array is sorted and checked for differences. If they are close, we reject the sample and call for another draw. I use https://github.com/jacobmenick/sampling code for multinomial sampling, there are other libraries as well.

Code, Node 12.1, Windows 10 x64

```
var multinom = SJS.Multinomial(100, [.02, .17, .33, .48]); // far away spacing of means n*p_i

q = multinom.draw().sort((a, b) => a - b); // sorted sample from multinomial
m = [] // array of pairwise differences, with first element removed
for (var k = 0; k < q.length - 1; ++k) {
    var curr = q[k];
    var next = q[k + 1];
    m.push(next - curr);
}
reject = m.some(el => el < 4); // check for pairwise distance, if true reject sample and get another one
s = q.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0); // check for sum, should be always 100
console.log(q);
console.log(m);
console.log(reject);
console.log(s);
```